# how to append column data from different csv files in one folder

Tags: pandas

I have some of csv files which i need to add special column from another file in one folder and save into one file. Lets i give an example below.

1.csv                 2.csv              3.csv           n.csv (and so on i have several csv file)

```
a   b   c   d        a   b   c   d      a   b   c   d    a   b   c   d
1   2   3   4        8   3   5   7      2   9   4   6    3   6   8   3
4   2   8   3        6   3   6   7      9   3   4   5    3   6   6   8
3   9   4   8        9   3   4   2      4   7   4   4    1   8   3   5
```

i want to append only column a and b, like an example below

x.csv

```
a   b   a   b   a   b   a   b
1   2   8   3   2   9   3   6
4   2   6   3   9   3   3   6
3   9   9   3   4   7   1   8
```

can some one help me how to add a column?

Comment: Have you managed to read a csv file with pd.read_csv ()?

Comment: Dear ansev, i have tried using pd.read_csv the column does not add on the right side but actually the rows were added below

Comment: import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import csv

path = "C:/Users/SYIFAAZRA/Documents/belajar_wradlib/Skew-T/"
os.chdir(path)

file = glob.glob("*.csv")


x=0
for files in file:
    x=x+1
    
    df = pd.read_csv(files, delimiter=',', skiprows=7, usecols=[11, 22])
    df1 = df.merge(df, how='right')
    df2 = pd.concat([df1])
    
print (df2)